# Access password protected shared network

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

How to read/write files in a shared network drive?

I am creating an application to upload files to the password protected shared network drive. When I run locally, the files are uploaded well. But, in the publish environment it throws:

> Access to the Path '/shared network drive/' is denied

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1) Create a network drive connection to the remote machine (so it appears to your computer as "X:" for example) and save to that.

2) Use the full UNC path specification: //RemoteMachineName/SharedFolder/foldername

Comment: I tried the first way. I mapped the particular folder of shared network drive to the remote machine and then published it.
It throws "given path's string is not supported"

I mapped it to my Y:
and the connection path is "\\Y:shared_folder_name\\". I used  path.combine for combining network drive Y and filename.

Comment: Instead, you can use Environment.SpecialFolder

Comment: Finally Solved.... In the application pool in IIS, under Advanced Settings, in Process Model, specify the credentials in Identity.

This got worked.

The reason is IIS needs a valid credentials for read/write in password protected network drive.